# Can I access an SFTP server via an SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, sftp, winscp

I have a Linux server with IP `1.2.3.4` which can access an SFTP server `2.2.2.2`. The SFTP only allows access from the IP `1.2.3.4`. Now I also want to access the SFTP server from my Windows computer using WinScp/an SFTP client. Can that be done using an SSH tunnel? which command would I have to issue on the Linux server to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do anything on the server. WinSCP (and other SFTP clients) [can tunnel through the intermediate server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel) on its own.

See the [Tunnel page of its Advanced site settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel).

[image]

Comment: awesome, that worked immediately on my first attempt. Thanks also to the other answers, but that one could be directly applied with ease :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect local port 222 to remote port 22 on 2.2.2.2
`ssh -L 222:2.2.2.2:22 user@1.2.3.4`